# Create ordered Arrays with JSONObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Let me explain my problem. 
(I'm new to java so maybe this type of thing might be easy but I can't figure it out !)

I have a JSONObject which looks like :

```
    {  
      notes:[  
       {  
         "scolaryear":2013,
         "codemodule":"B-CPE-042",
         "titlemodule":"B1 - Unix & C Lab Seminar",
         "codeinstance":"NCE-1-1",
         "codeacti":"acti-134315",
         "title":"Piscine Jour 1",
         "date":"2013-10-04 13:33:51",
         "correcteur":"ramassage-tek",
         "final_note":0,
         "comment":"Ex_00 -> output differs"
       },
       {} // And so on .. 
      ] 
    }
```

For now I can get all the data doing something like :

```
try {
 // Pulling items from the array
 JSONArray notesArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("notes");
 try {
  ListView lv = (ListView) _modulesActivity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
  List < String > notesList = new ArrayList < String > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < notesArr.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject tmp = notesArr.getJSONObject(i);
   String code_module = tmp.getString("codemodule");
   String module = tmp.getString("titlemodule");
   String title = tmp.getString("title");
   String final_note = tmp.getString("final_note");
   String year = tmp.getString("scolaryear");
   String comment = tmp.getString("comment");

   String display = year + " | " + title + " | " + final_note;
   notesList.add(display);
  }
  ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (
   _mainContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesList);

  lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(_mainContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(_mainContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So with that technique I got all my data in one array and an only listView which looks like :

- 2014 | PROJECT #1 | 13/20
- 2015 | PROJECT #2 | 20/20

But I need to order my data with year, and module.

It would look like :

```
> YEAR (year)
   > TITLE OF MODULE (module) - MODULE CODE (codemodule)
     > PROJECT NAME (title) | MARK (final_note)
       - COMMENT (comment)
```

You have a first header with the year, when you click on a year, you can see all the module :

```
> MODULE #1
> MODULE #2 
...
```

And when you click on a module you can see all project :

```
> PROJECT #1 | MARK : 20
> PROJECT #2 | MARK : 13 
...
```

And finally when you click on a project you can see the comment !

```
^ PROJECT #1 | MARK : 20 
   - Great project .. bla bla bla
```

(or maybe display a popup window which contains the comments if it's possible)

I know it may be a complexe thing but I really want to achieve that !

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: U need to implement https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/ and customize it as per ur need.

Comment: What you can do is get Date from string store it in object of note  format it (choice of your format something like yyyy-MM-dd) and then Use Comparator  to campare object of a list by date it will sort your date ascending by default.

Comment: what you want to display in your list Item of listview ?? kindly text that things here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution !

I used this library : https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

Here is my Code :

```
try {
 // Pulling items from the array
 TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
 TreeNode child;
 String year = "YEAR";
 String moduleName = "";
 YearHolder.IconTreeItem nodeItem = new YearHolder.IconTreeItem(1, year);
 ModuleHolder.IconTreeItem nodeModule = new ModuleHolder.IconTreeItem(1, moduleName);
 TreeNode parent = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new YearHolder(_mainContext));
 TreeNode parentModule = new TreeNode(nodeModule).setViewHolder(new ModuleHolder(_mainContext));
 JSONArray modArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("notes");
 try {
  for (int i = 0; i < modArr.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject tmp = modArr.getJSONObject(i);
   /*String title = tmp.getString("title");*/
   String final_note = tmp.getString("final_note");
   String newModuleName = tmp.getString("titlemodule");
   String newYear = tmp.getString("scolaryear");
   if (!(newYear.equals(year))) {
    year = newYear;
    nodeItem = new YearHolder.IconTreeItem(1, year);
    parent = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new YearHolder(_mainContext));
    root.addChild(parent);
   }
   if (!(newModuleName.equals(moduleName))) {
    moduleName = newModuleName;
    nodeModule = new ModuleHolder.IconTreeItem(1, moduleName);
    parentModule = new TreeNode(nodeModule).setViewHolder(new ModuleHolder(_mainContext));
    parent.addChild(parentModule);
   }
   NoteHolder.IconTreeItem nodeNote = new NoteHolder.IconTreeItem(1, final_note);
   child = new TreeNode(nodeNote).setViewHolder(new NoteHolder(_mainContext));
   parentModule.addChildren(child);

   /*String display = year + " | " + title + " | " + final_note;*/
  }
  AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(_notesActivity, root);
  _notesActivity.setContentView(tView.getView());
 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(_mainContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(_mainContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

YearHolder class looks like this :

```
public class YearHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<YearHolder.IconTreeItem> {

    public YearHolder (Context context ) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, IconTreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_notes_view, null, false);
        TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        tvValue.setText(value.text);

        return view;
    }

    public static class IconTreeItem {
        public int icon;
        public String text;

        IconTreeItem(int icon_, String text_) {
            this.icon = icon_;
            this.text = text_;
        }
    }
}
```

Super easy to use !

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you have two possibilities:

1. Implement a Note Java object, during the form initialize this objects and put them in an ArrayList. In the end sort it with some algorithm.
   For example it would look like:

   ```
   List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<Note>();
   for (int i = 0; i < notesArr.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject tmp = notesArr.getJSONObject(i);
       noteListe.add(new Note(tmp.getString("codemodule"), tmp.getString("titlemodule"),...);
   }
   ```

   Now sort it with a proper method and in the end print it maybe overriding toString() Note method.
2. If possible sort the JsonObjectArray when you create it.

Hope it can help you

Comment: Yes Rather using List of String use list of Notes object and then Implement Comparetor on Notes Obect from list and it will sort your problem.